# value of a Model property send as a parameters to controller method in bootstrap-fileinput

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io, fileinputstream

I'm using the [Bootstrap File Input plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) and I'm trying to get the `product_ID` Model property value from following form and send as a parameters to controller method.

this is the form

```
@model project_name.Models.relavantmodel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_ID)

   <input id="idd" type="file" class="file">

   // form sumbit button
   <input type = "submit" value="Create" /> 

}
```

I have following controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult UploadFiles(string product_ID, string type)
    {
      .........
    }
```

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314751/bootstrap-file-input-plugin-getting-the-form-data-to-the-controller) also

I'm trying to use following script for call upload method and send parameters

---

**Approach 1 :**

```
$("#idd").fileinput({
    type: 'POST',   
    uploadUrl: '/Home/UploadFiles', // server upload action
    uploadExtraData: { 'product_ID': document.getElementById('#Product_ID').value, 'type': "marketing_materials_EN" },

});
```

---

**Approach 2 :**

```
$("#idd").fileinput({
    type: 'POST',        
    uploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home")',
    uploadExtraData: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), 'type': "marketing_materials_EN" },
```

---

**Approach 3 :**

```
 $("#idd").fileinput({
        type: 'POST',        
        uploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home" ,new {product_ID = @Model.Product_ID , type = "marketing_materials_EN" })',
```

---

**Approach 4 :**

```
$("#idd").fileinput({

      uploadUrl: '/Home/UploadFiles',
      uploadExtraData: function () {
          return {
                  extradata: JSON.stringify({ product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), type: "marketing_materials_EN"})
          };
```

---

**Approach 5 :**

```
$("#idd").fileinput({

      uploadUrl: '/Home/UploadFiles',
      uploadExtraData: function () {
          return {
                  extradata: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), type: "marketing_materials_EN"}
          };
```

But above approach 1, 2 and 3 , I cannot get the `product_ID` that I'm inserting, .But I can send `type`

Once I put debug point at controller method I can see `type` value that is getting like below

[image]

and `product_ID` getting `NULL`

[image]

Approach 4 and 5 , getting null for both `product_ID` and `type` parameters

How can I get the `product_ID` here

Comment: In all three approaches are you able to post `type` value to controller? Also did you check putting an `alert` in script to see if the `Product_ID` value is getting properly before posting to controller? Also try with `JSON.Stringify({ product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val(), 'type': "marketing_materials_EN" })`.

Comment: @SivaGopal yes I can see the value for `type` In all three approaches . 
I cannot use alert inside `.fileinput({` .

Once I use your suggestion `uploadExtraData: JSON.Stringify({ product_ID: $('Product_ID').val(), 'type': "marketing_materials_EN" }),` its disappearing  `Bootstrap File Input plugin`

Comment: ok, did you try `alert` approach?

Comment: @SivaGopal  I cannot use alert inside `.fileinput({` getting error

Comment: Can you check in Fiddler or Browser developer tools(IE/Chrome) by pressing F12 or FireBug in Firefox, what values getting posted to server in the request?

Comment: IE/Chrome) by pressing F12 , whats section should I look at ?